# Evaluate Integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^4x}{x^4}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Find $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^4x}{x^4}$ using the fact that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$. The graph of $\dfrac{\sin^4x}{x^4}$ was also given, I tried to integrate by parts repeatedly but it got too messy and confusing. Is there a clever way around this?

Comment: are you trying to find if this is convergent?

Comment: No, trying to find the value of the integral.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says $\pi/3$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+infty+%5Cfrac%7Bsin%5E4x%7D%7Bx%5E4%7D

Comment: yes I know the answer

Comment: I need to do this without complex analysis

Comment: One of the answers in Bot's link has the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I have an answer using repeatedly integration by parts, you may have a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4667/146687) if you're interested.

Comment: I don't understand the last two steps. What happens to the term in $sin^{2}2x$?

Comment: @user140161 Set $2x\mapsto x$